# Adding nil object to auto release pool not crashing

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

I am adding a nil object to autorelease pool. But it is not crashing the application. Why?? Any one can give an explanation for this please? The code I tested given below,

```
    UIView *testView = nil;
    [testView autorelease];
```

Thanks,
Augustine P A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending *any* message to `nil` always results in nothing happening. No `autorelease` method gets called -- the message dispatch mechanism stops immediately when the receiver is `nil`.